# Cordova camrera plugin response not saved properly while creating images file

Tags: angularjs, cordova, android-camera, cordova-plugins

I am using `cordova camera plugin` with `data_uri` option for taking picture from my application  and save .In server side i got the image in `base64` encoded string. But corrupted image are saved.But i used base64 encoded string directly and it saved correctly in server side.

```
$image_code = $_REQUEST['imageCode']; $file = uniqid() . '.jpg'; $success = file_put_contents($file, base64_decode($image_code)); echo "uploaded";
```

If any issues in my implementation. Thanks

Comment: which HTTP method you are using ? GET or POST ?

Comment: Used POST Method .

Comment: Issue because of content not posted fully , Removed all headers from ajax call it posted successfully

Comment: does that mean your issue is resolved ?

Comment: Yes @Arpit issue solved , base64 encoded datas are not fully transfered to server when i am using some headers and content types , removed headers and its works for me